# Clean up after response is returned to client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Context:**

I have an endpoint that is used to download a zip archive.

```
@GetMapping
public DeferredResult<StreamingResponseBody> download(/**params**/) {

}
```

Due to the number of files and file sizes, keeping all of them in memory is not possible (i.e. I have to read chunks of files from an external service, store them to a temporary directory, create a zip archive, write files in chunks to the zip, delete all temporary files after the archiving is done - *at this point I am left only with the archive on disk* - and afterwards stream the zip back to the client).

I've managed to implement the functionality, but I am not sure which is the best way to clean up after a request (note that the service is used by multiple clients - so multiple downloads should be able to happen simultaneously).

Currently, I am using a `HandlerInterceptor` that generates a random name for the archive in the `preHandle` method and passes it along as a request attribute. The request attribute is passed along to the service that generates the archive and is used as archive name. Then, in the `afterCompletion` method of the interceptor, I read the archive name from the request attribute and delete the archive.

```
class ZipInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public static final String ZIP_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "zipName";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(isApplicable(request)){
            request.setAttribute(ZIP_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, generateZipName());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        if(isApplicable(request)){
            deleteZip((String)request.getAttribute(ZIP_ATTRIBUTE_NAME));
        }
    }
}
```

**Another approaches that I've considered:**

- Returning the archive name to the client (as a header or as the name of the downloaded file) and relying on the client to call a new endpoint to delete the archive. The main drawback is that I have no way of forcing the clients into using this protocol (and might end up with the disk full).
- Run a job every hour (or another time interval) and clean old archives. The drawback is that I don't know for sure weather a file finished streaming back to the clients or not (so for a big enough file any time interval will delete a file that is not finished streaming yet).

Which would be, in your opinion, the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Why store the archive (and the files) on the disk in the first place? You can simply wrap the response output stream into a ZipOutputStream, and write the zip directly to the response.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @ZB Nizet. That is one way it could be refactored and avoid the problem all together. I will use your solution and avoid creating the zip on disk (which, as you pointed out, adds no value), but due to some constraints I still have to write the files to disk. In this case, I won't have a zip, but a directory of files to clean up. Are you aware of any way I can achieve that (which would be the same scenario as the one initially defined, with a directory instead of a zip archive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JB Nizet pointed out in the comments, the best approach would be to **not store the files on disk at all**.

If your specific context left you with files on disk after the request is returned to the client, you could use the next approach to get rid of them.

```
class CleanupInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // do cleanup here
    }
}
```

If anyone finds a more elegant solution to tackle this, please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation. I think the most safest way is to go with creating a background job to clean up the files. I added a timestamp to the file name that I created. Then the background job will filter out the files that are at least 30 mins older than current time and delete them. That way I know for sure that those files are already finished streaming and safe to delete