# Spring @RestController - after request being served

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

**Background**

here is the method defined in @RestController, it reads file from disk then stream back.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bill", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getbill(){
  ...
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
  InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(in);
  httpHeaders.setContentLength(file.Length());
  return new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Issue**

I would like to delete the file after request is served, but unable to find a good place.

I would assume it should be after inputStream gets closed (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java#L117) . it can not be done in above method since file is opened by Inputstream.

**Answer Summary** 
Thank you all for helping with this.

The accepted answer requires least change and working well.

Comment: Use a `ScheduledExecutorService`? Perhaps wrap the `InputStreamResource` and delete the file from the `close()` method?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-output-stream

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387380/clean-up-after-response-is-returned-to-client

Comment: FWIW: It'd be better practice to move the work from the controller to a `@Service`. That would make deleting the file in the process of generating the return trivial. However, I agree with Gerben Jongerius's answer below - GET should be idempotent; DELETE is the appropriate call for destroying the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `FileInputStream` with your own implementation and then overwrite `close`. When the input stream is closed, your file gets deleted as well.

```
public class MyFileInputStream extends FileInputStream {
    private final File myFile;

    public MyFileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file);
        myFile = file;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        myFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that it is bad practice in a RESTfull service to perform destructive operations on GET requests this can not be done by the default Java libraries. The more widely accepted implementation would be a GET that streams the file followed by a DELETE call to remove the file.

But you can do it by implementing your own InputStream, see an earlier thread in Stackoverflow on [deleting files on closing a InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693968/is-there-an-existing-fileinputstream-delete-on-close).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are creating the file in the same controller.
You can use:

```
 try (BufferedWriter out = Files
        .newBufferedWriter(newFilePath, Charset.defaultCharset(),
            StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE)) {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(newFilePath.toFile());
        InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(in);
        httpHeaders.setContentLength(file.Length());
        return new ResponseEntity(inputStreamResource, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

As the BufferedWriter will close on return, the file will get deleted.

Comment: Doesn't it make a new temporary file on the physical file system?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @phlogratos's answer, you can try like this.

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download() throws Exception {

    ... codes ...

    InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file) {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
            logger.info("export:'{}':" + (isDeleted ? "deleted" : "preserved"), filename);
        }
    });
    return new ResponseEntity<>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```